# How can I tell a local Rack server (pow.cx) to proxy to tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, pow.cx

So, I use pow.cx to power most of my static localhost needs - I have managed to get it to serve php through rack-legacy, too.

However, I now find myself in a position where I need to use Tomcat for a project, but I would like to still make use of Pow as far as is possible. The reasons for this are multiple, but basically I would rather serve everything other than the parts that require java via rack.

I was wondering if there might be a way to tell pow to proxy off requests to the locally running tomcat server on port 8081? I figured the config.ru could probably be told to do some of this, but I don't really know how (as I'm not really a Ruby expert).

If anyone can help here that would be great. I have found some similar topics on SO, but nothing that seems to quite fit with what I am trying to do here.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After no answers here I did some more digging and combined pieces of solutions found elsewhere together - The following is a combination of what I already knew from configuring pow to use rack-legacy to handle php files, and bits of knowledge from elsewhere on the internet:

The solution lies in another gem : rack-reverse-proxy.

If you don't already have the gem installed simply run

```
gem install rack-reverse-proxy
```

from the command line

Once you have that installed, it is a relatively simple matter of modifying an existing config.ru file from a php project to fit here and have pow forward on all requests to Tomcat.

Assuming that your local tomcat server is running on port 8001:

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/reverse_proxy'
require 'rack-rewrite'

INDEXES = ['index.html','index.php', 'index.cgi']

ENV['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] = "HTTP/1.1"

use Rack::ReverseProxy do
   # Set :preserve_host to true globally (default is true already)
   reverse_proxy_options :preserve_host => true

   # Forward the path /* to tomcat. 
   # You can limit this to requests to certain paths by providing a more specific 
   # path as the first argument
   reverse_proxy '/', 'http://localhost:8081'
end

use Rack::ReverseProxy
run Rack::File.new Dir.getwd
```

It really was that simple after all that.

I hope this knowledge helps someone else in my strange situation in the future!